# get_comments not working properly after WordPress v4.4 update

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming, comments

I just found a wired thing on my website after v4.4 update. In my blog pages I use 2 functions to fetch comments.

First I use

```
 wp_list_comments( array( "callback" => "checkout_comment", "type" => "comment") );
```

To fetch the comments only. Then I run a count check if any trackbacks exists by using

```
$trackback_count =  get_comments( array(
                                                    'status' => 'approve',
                                                    'post_id'=> get_the_ID(), 
                                                    'type'=> 'pings', 
                                                    'count' => true)
                                                 );
```

and if the do exists the I show the trackbacks/pingsbacks like this

```
wp_list_comments( array( "callback" => "checkout_comment", "type" => "pings", "reply_text" => null, "format" => "html5") );
```

Now, after v4.4 update the comments are showing fine but the trackbacks list are not showing.

Can anyone tell me why? What I might need to change to fix this?